# Defining the order topology on the natural numbers

Tags: general-topology

How might one go about defining the order topology on the natural numbers with natural order (<)? I'm working on constructing the basis for the topology, and I realize that the intervals [1,b) and (a,b) must be present in the basis, since 1 is the least element of the naturals, but I'm not sure how to finish it off and properly describe the topology

Comment: The order topology on the naturals is the discrete topology.

Comment: The set $[1,2)$ is open in the order topology, as are the sets $(n-1,n+1)$ for all $n\ge 2$. What topology do those open sets generate?

Comment: Just adding details to complement the previous comment (and leave less work to be done/verified): $[1,2)=\{1\}$ (when our set is the natural numbers) and $(n-1,n+1)=\{n\}$ for $n\ge2$. So every singleton $\{n\}$ for $n\ge1$ is open, and if $A$ is any set of natural numbers then $A=\cup\{\{n\}:n\in A\}$ which is open, as the union of open singletons.

Answer (score 0):

$[1,2) = \{1\}$ in $(\Bbb N, <)$, so $\{1\}$ is basic open, as you mentioned.

For all $n >1$, $(n-1,n+1) = \{n\}$ is basic open (as an open interval).

But if all singletons are in the base for the order topology, *all* subsets of $\Bbb N$ are open, being unions of those. So we get the discrete topology. Nothing new but a valid order topology on such a "discrete" order.

Answer (score 0):

So $A$ is an open set if every $a\in A$ is an interior point.

$a$ is an interior point if there is an $r> 0$ so $N_r(a) = \{n\in \mathbb N: d(n,a)= |n-a| < r\}\subset A$.

$N_r(a) = \{n\in \mathbb N: |n-a|< r\} =\{n\in \mathbb N: a-r < n < a+r\}$.  If $r < \frac 12$ then $N_{\frac 12}(a) = \{n\in \mathbb N: a-\frac 12 < n < a+ \frac 12\} = \{a\}$.

And as $a \in A$ then $\{a\} \subset A$ so $a$ is *always* an interior point of any set it belongs to.

So... all sets are open.  And that's the discrete topology

Comment: You're using the metric topology not the *order* topology.